# universal analytics stability

Tags: ios, reusability, universal-analytics, stability

I've had issues with either google ads or google analytics
in the past (crashes in pre ARC times).
How stable is their ios code these days?

P.S. bonus question: how easy it's to reuse that sdk
to point it to a server of my own (self hosting)?
thanks

UPD: no public api for changing the server was found,
the line of thinking probably was: there is no source code
for the sdk, so why bother allowing user to untether themselves
from the mothership